# PHPUnit: get arguments to a mock method call

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I'm currently working on a project that stores sensitive data, and must therefore be able to erase them on request.

I'd like to test that my entity (patient) is saved to the database with a null phone number. First idea to do that: get the argument passed to `PatientDao::savePatient(PatientModel $patient)`, and have a look at its `phoneNumber` attribute.

So here is the `PatientDao` interface:

```
interface PatientDao {
    function savePatient(PatientModel $patient);
}
```

And the code in my test file:

```
$this->patientDao                    // This is my mock
            ->expects($this->once()) 
            ->method('savePatient'); // savePatient() must be called once

$this->controller->handleMessage(...);

$patient = ??; // How can I get the patient to make assertions with it ?
```

How can I do that, or is there any other way to make sure the patient is saved with a null phone number?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can make assertions on the argument using `returnCallback()`. Remember to call assert functions statically via `PHPUnit_Framework_Assert` because you cannot use `self` inside a closure.

```
$this->patientDao
        ->expects($this->once()) 
        ->method('savePatient')
        ->will($this->returnCallback(function($patient) {
            PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertNull($patient->getPhoneNumber());
        }));
```

Comment: Worked a treat here. Note: if the argument takes multiple parameters, you need to include them all, even if you don't want to test them all. e.g. `$this->returnCallback(function($patient, $someOtherParameter) {})`.

Answer (score 15):

Here's the trick I used. I added this private method to my test class:

```
private function captureArg( &$arg ) {
    return $this->callback( function( $argToMock ) use ( &$arg ) {
        $arg = $argToMock;
        return true;
    } );
}
```

Then when setting up the mock:

```
$mock->expects( $this->once() )
    ->method( 'someMethod' )
    ->with( $this->captureArg( $arg ) );
```

After that, `$arg` contains the value of the argument passed to the mock.

Answer (score 4):

Make the Mock objects method return the first argument:

```
$this->patientDao                    // This is my mock
            ->expects($this->once()) 
            ->method('savePatient') // savePatient() must be called once
            ->with($this->returnArgument(0));
```

You can then assert that it is `NULL`.

Comment: I've never used $this->return* in the "with"... Looks interesting! But how can I get the value itself later in my test function, how is it actually returned to me ?

Comment: Are you using the mock to do introspection?

Comment: I don't think so... I guess no.

Comment: I think that should be `->will(...)`, but I haven't used `returnArgument()` before. But I don't think this will work unless the DAO returns whatever `savePatient()` returns.

Answer (score 2):

One thing - inside the closure you still can access $this, in that case it gives you:

```php
$this->patientDao
    ->expects($this->once()) 
    ->method('savePatient')
    ->will($this->returnCallback(function($patient) {
        $this->assertNull($patient->getPhoneNumber());
    }));
```